# I have a parse error in my php code

Tags: php

I have a piece of code which I am struggling on. I want the onclick function to display the "Question" row in the function but when I place `'$questionrow['QuestionContent']'` within the brackets, it is giving me an error stating:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /xxx7/Mobile_app/previousquestions.php on line 119

How do I place the QuestionContent within the brackets correctly in function below:

```
 onclick='parent.addwindow('$questionrow['QuestionContent']');'>Add</button>
```

Below is whole code:

```
<?php

$output = "";

        while ($questionrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($questionresult)) {
$output .= "
<table>
      <tr>
<td class='questiontd'>{$questionrow['QuestionContent']}</td>
      <td class='addtd'><button type='button' class='add' onclick='parent.addwindow('$questionrow['QuestionContent']');'>Add</button></td>
      </tr>";
        }
        $output .= "        </table>";

        echo $output;

        ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `{}` around it like you did with the first one:

```
'parent.addwindow('{$questionrow['QuestionContent']}');'>
```

Comment: When I try your code it now states I have a syntax error in firebug stating that I have a missing ')', but I don't see a missing bracket. Why am I getting this error

Comment: Try <button type='button' class='add' onclick="parent.addwindow('{$questionrow['QuestionContent']}');">Add</button> ... notice the " for the onclick

Comment: It is now giving me this error when I try your theory: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /web/stud/xxx/Mobile_app/previousquestions.php on line 119`

Comment: Escape the `"`'s : `<button type='button' class='add' onclick=\"parent.addwindow('{$questionrow['QuestionContent']}');\">Add</button>`

Answer (score 1):

I find it much easier to close your string and concatenate with the period. It easier to read than encapsulating them in curly brackets.

```
<?php
$output = "";
while ($questionrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($questionresult))
{
    $output .= "
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class='questiontd'>" . $questionrow['QuestionContent'] . "</td>
            <td class='addtd'><button type='button' class='add' onclick='parent.addwindow('" . $questionrow['QuestionContent'] . "');'>Add</button></td>
        </tr>";
}
$output .= "</table>";
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: Still giving same syntax error